# How to set the product store view in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to programmatically changes the product from default store view into all store view.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you need to assign same product to other store programetically?

Comment: Yes   ............

Comment: I post answer kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

```
/** @var  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory */
 protected $productFactory;

 $storeId = 2;
 $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load('YOURPRODUCTID');
 $productStoreView->setStoreId($storeId);
 $productStoreView->save();
```